# Error While Starting Eureka Server in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot Application Created from the Spring Initializer with a dependency on Eureka Server. 
When I try to start the application I am getting the below errors. This is happening even without any changes.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demodiscoveryserver.DemoDiscoveryServerApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demodiscoveryserver.DemoDiscoveryServerApplication.main(DemoDiscoveryServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:499) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addMetaAnnotationsToQueue(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:85) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addAllMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:68) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.createMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:251) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:247) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:186) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:173) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.of(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:634) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotation.of(MergedAnnotation.java:596) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.visitEnd(MergedAnnotationReadingVisitor.java:96) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readElementValues(ClassReader.java:2985) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:695) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:992) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Below is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-discovery-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is the Application code.

```
package com.example.demodiscoveryserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DemoDiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoDiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am pretty new to Java. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please share your main application class

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring starter web dependency in you pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I might have accidentally removed it while trying different things to make it work.

Comment: Can you remove the spring-context dependency and try again. It is not necessary to add that dependency

Answer (score 0):

Example of a running project based on your question: https://github.com/thiagochagas/eureka-server

**Remove** the "spring-context" from your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a src/main/resources/application.properties with this example:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

I would suggest you to clean/invalidate the caches of your dependencies(when using IDE).

Execute in your project home folder:

```
./mvnw clean install
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Access in your browser at localhost:8761 :
[image]